oauth2-server customizations: client_id, client_secret, jwt tokens
I am trying to implement an oauth2 server using oauth2-server and am running into a few points of confusion.  I would like the frontend of my app to determine when a user is no longer logged in and redirect the user to a login form.  Once the user clicks submit, the oauth2-server will authenticate the user and return an authorization code which the app will use to retrieve the access token (jwt).
I coded the oauth2-server, providing the necessary overloads but am confused on a few points.

I know the specs require a client_id and client_secret, where in the pipeline would I create these items, at registration or some other process flow?
Is there a way to return and configure a jwt token as opposed to an access token?
For the token endpoint, if I am trying to authenticate a user with their username and password, is there a way to disable the client id requirement?

